# Table View resizes under tab bar after autoresizing from iPhone 8 to iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Table View is under the tab bar with these autoresizing settings. This is only a problem for iPhones without a home button.

I have tried setting constraints and changing the autoresize with no luck.

Screenshots here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVgg5.jpg

Comment: Is your bottom constraint to safe area? If it is, try changing it to superview.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasElPapu. That did the trick somehow!

Answer (score 1):

Add the bottom constraint to superview fixed it. Thanks to @NicolasElPapu in the comments.